# Routing error mixing Web Forms and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing, webforms-routing

I am working on a Web Forms Web Application with mixed in MVC. I have followed the instructions from this page http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-aspnet-webforms-and-aspnet-mvc and it works fine in VS2010 developer server but when I try to publish it to a MVC enabled IIS 6 browser is not automatically redirect to default.aspx  after login and I get a 404 error at the root of the application.

My Global.asax.cs looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
    }
```

If I comment out the call to RegisterRoutes in Application_Start method the automatic redirect to default.aspx works but then the MVC parts fail.

I need some help with how to setup the routing to enable automatic redirect to default.aspx while enabling the MVC routing. The MVC parts is located under a specific path like so: myserver/applicationname/mvcparts.

Asp.Net MVC 3 is installed on both developer machine and server where I publish.

Comment: A clarification: All direct access to pages with extensions (page.aspx (web forms)) works fine. It is after login that the browser brings up myserver/myApplication and not to myserver/myApplication/default.aspx as it does on my developer machine. This is where I get the 404. When I then update the url to point do default.aspx or som other aspx page all is well.

Answer (score 1):

That's because IIS6 doesn't support extensionless urls by default. You will need to [configure it](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx). And if you are not using ASP.NET 4, [this is for you](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx). If you don't configure it; IIS6 doesn't know that `/Home/Index` must be associated with the `aspnet_isapi` filter. It doesn't even know that this is an ASP.NET application. That's the reason why in classic WebForms, they used the `.aspx` extension which is associated with the aspnet_isapi filter when you install .NET.

Extensionless urls are supported by IIS7+ out-of-the-box when running in integrated pipeline mode.

Comment: I cant really see a solution to my problem in the link to Haacks blog you provided, what I read there is that it should work. He got a 403 but I get a 404. .Net 4 is installed. In fact my problem is that extentionless urls work in my application but the defaultDocument, default.aspx does not.

Comment: @Riddler777, what default document? In an ASP.NET application you normally don't have a default.aspx file.

Comment: defaultDocument is set in the configuration of the virtual directory in IIS.

Comment: @Riddler777, yes I know where is it set. My question was do you have such file `default.aspx` in your ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: It is a Web Forms Web Application with MVC under a specific folder (myserver/app/mvcparts). In the root of the application there is a default.aspx, so yes.